# LINQ to SQL: Store single record in memory by value (should not change after SubmitChanges)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm pretty sure there must already be such a question but I just can't find it.

I would like to retrieve a record from SQL via LINQ and store it in a variable. 
Then I would like to update the data, but the variable should still contain the old values.  The variable should basically store the record "by value".

For multiple records I can use .ToList() to retrieve the data and store it in memory, but what is the best way to do it for a single record?

Example:

```
var record = dc.MyTable.Where(p => p.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
var orignalRecord = ??;

record.Name == "New Value";
dc.SubmitChanges();

//Now I would like orignalRecord.Name to still have "Old Name".
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not supported natively, but you have two choices to implement it yourself:

1. Define `Clone` method in your object class like this (This way only supports shallow copy):

   ```
   class MyTable
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public MyTable Clone()
       {
           return (MyTable)MemberwiseClone();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement method that serialize and deserialize your object using serializers like `Newtonsoft` (This way supports deep copy)